# Simplifying a path on a two dimensional grid

Tags: arrays, algorithm, optimization, path, grid

Im generating a path from point A to point B on a two dimensional grid, which returns an array of points for my unit to travel through, each element in the array has an X and Y coordinate.

red dot is the path start and the blue one the end, brown points are points contained in the array (the array also includes the start and end points),
green line is the path.

[image]

how can I simplify this path to something like this?
[image]

Comment: What's the definition of "optimize" and what's the constraints?  And what is the research or ideas you've been trying, want to share?

Comment: @DanielHao my bad, I meant simplify the path at hand, the only requirement is that the path itself (the green line) stays the same as before while reducing the number of points (brown), so far Ive tried looping over the points and comparing each points "direction"  to the point before, however this resulted in a deformed path

Comment: Do you mean the "shortest path", maybe?

Comment: No, I get my points from an A* algorithm, im just trying to remove unneeded points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we consider 3 points on your input path `(p0,p1,p2)` we want to remove the middle point `p1` when the following condition is true:

```
(p1.x - p0.x)    (p2.x - p1.x)
------------- == -------------
(p1.y - p0.y)    (p2.y - p1.y)
```

Or equivalently, and avoiding the risk of division by zero:

```
(p1.x - p0.x) * (p2.y - p1.y) == (p1.y - p0.y) * (p2.x - p1.x)
```

Here's some Java code to illustrate:

```
static List<Point> simplify(List<Point> poly)
{
    if(poly.size() < 3) return new ArrayList<>(poly);
    
    List<Point> spoly = new ArrayList<>();
    
    spoly.add(poly.get(0));
    for(int i = 0, dx = 0, dy = 0; i < poly.size()-1; i++)
    {
        Point p0 = poly.get(i);
        Point p1 = poly.get(i+1);
        
        int x = p1.x - p0.x;
        int y = p1.y - p0.y;
        
        if(i > 0 && (dx * y != dy * x)) 
            spoly.add(poly.get(i));
        
        dx = x;
        dy = y;
    }
    spoly.add(poly.get(poly.size()-1));
    
    return spoly;
}
```

Test:

```
List<Point> poly = 
   Arrays.asList(p(0, 0), p(1, 1), p(2, 2), p(3, 3), p(4, 3), p(5, 3), p(6, 3));

System.out.println(simplify(poly));
```

Output:

```
[(0, 0), (3, 3), (6, 3)]
```